# Protractor - Element is not clickable at point (968, 23)

Tags: testing, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing testcase on logout functionality. When the code is executed it show element is notclickable at point.

```js
  element.all(by.css('.dropdown-user a')).then(function(items) {
        items[0].click();
        ptor.sleep(500);
    });
```

```html
view.html

<li class="dropdown dropdown-user">
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="logout" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
  <img alt="" class="img-circle" src="../../assets/admin/layout/img/avatar3_small.jpg"/>
  <span class="username username-hide-on-mobile">
      </span>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
 </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
   <a href=""><i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><i class="icon-calendar"></i> My Calendar </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><i class="icon-envelope-open"></i> My Inbox <span class="badge badge-danger">3 </span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><i class="icon-rocket"></i> My Tasks <span class="badge badge-success">7 </span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="divider">
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=""><i class="icon-lock"></i> Lock Screen </a>
  </li>
  <li ng-click="logout()">
   <a href=""><i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Is there any way to oprn this dropdown? Could you please let me know how to write the code to test it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the xpath way 
//li[contains(@class, 'dropdown')]/ul[contains(@class, 'dropdown')].

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for